# Simple JSP website

Tags: java, jsp, jspinclude

I'm looking for help/advice with creating simple JSP website using equivalent of PHP include+switch function.

The goal is that I want to be able to switch between multiple JSP include pages in one main page.

What would be the simplest possible form of above 'function'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you have the [`<jsp:include>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref2020.html#8828) for. You can use [EL](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) to specify the `page` attribute.

Create a `/WEB-INF/main.jsp` file which look like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:include page="${page}" />
    </body>
</html>
```

You can control the `${page}` value with help of a page controller servlet. Something like:

```
public class PageController extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("page", "/WEB-INF" + request.getPathInfo());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/main.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Map this servlet in `web.xml` as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>pageController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.PageController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>pageController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/page/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This way the servlet is accessible through `http://example.com/context/page/foo.jsp` and in this URL example it will then get `/foo.jsp` from the pathinfo and thus set the `page` attribute with the value `/WEB-INF/foo.jsp` so that it is available in EL as `${page}` so that the `jsp:include` knows what it should include. No need for nasty scriptlets or switch statements.

In the `/WEB-INF/foo.jsp` you can just write down HTML as if it is placed inside the HTML `<body>` tag.

Note that the JSP files are placed in `/WEB-INF`, this is done so to prevent direct access by URL so that the users cannot request them without going through the page controller, such as for example `http://example.com/context/foo.jsp` which would only return the partial content (the to-be-included page).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Much more extensible solution than mine, just not quite as simple. ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<%  if ( expression1 ) { %>
    <%@ include file="file1.jspf" %>
<% } else if(expression2) { %>
    <%@ include file="file2.jspf" %>
<% } %>
```

Or, if you have the option, check out JSF2 and/or Facelets. It has much more powerful templating capabilities.

Comment: Scriptlets are bad. Use Java classes and taglibs/EL.

Comment: Don't disagree, but that would be the "simplest" way to solve that problem, IMO.